# Can you read messages in camunda like we do in Mqueue ?

Tags: apache-camel, camunda, mqueue

can we read messages in camunda like we do in Mqueue ? can camunda be a substitute for Apache camel routing framework ?

Comment: What kind of messages?

Comment: My question is whether we have any functionality in camunda which can read messages from the Mqueue ?

Answer (score 1):

Camunda is not a integration engine/framework, but it does support Apache Camel integration. Which means, Camunda will use Apache Camel for talking to MQueue.

Regardless, you need to give bit more context. There might not be any need for camunda + camel, Camel will be able to do stuff on its own / you may not need Camel as well.  All depends on the details you provide and what you want to achieve.